# Why did the operators just came to the house?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-guest

As the movie *The Guest* was quite consistent I can't figure out one thing - why did Major Carver, KPG executive, not carry out any kind of reconnaissance before trying to apprehended David. They could have observed the house through binoculars or at least approach it from front and back (basic movie stuff when two cops get some criminal and prevent him running through the back door). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Major Carver was too afraid from the consequences of David can cause that he doesn't want to delay the operation. As can be seen when he was in too hurry to get there. So he just doesn't want to waste any time in observation and want to act as fast he can.